# regarding textCanged event in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am creating a website which is having a textbox with ID txt5 which stores Customer_reference. All I want is to fill other textboxes having customer details automatically,when I type customer_reference value by fetching it. For this purpose I am using TextChanged event

```
 protected void txt5_TextChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = (Class1.con_string);
        con.Open();
        string query = string.Format("select cust_name from customer_master where cust_slno='{0}'",txt4 .Text .ToString ());
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(query,con);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        string type = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        txt6.Text = type;
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "alert(\"User successfully updated\");", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "alert(ex);", true);
    }
}
```

But the value of txt6 is not updating  Please help what's wrong in the coding.

Comment: Can you share the UI code on how you hook up the TextChanged event from the textbox

Comment: if you do not mark the textbox as autpostback=true, the event will not fire until the next postback occurs.

Comment: Also, the event will not fire until the textbox loses focus.  So it won't fire for each character entered.

Comment: Here is the UI code for the txt5 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt5" 
            ontextchanged="txt5_TextChanged1" AutoPostBack="True" 
            ondatabinding="txt5_TextChanged1"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling the event ondatabinding on your TextBox? See if removing this solve your problem.

Comment: this is also not solving the program. After writing in text5 its just reloading the form with txt5 value the form.

Comment: The only possibility is that your query is not returning data. or empty string.